# Unit test for Lucene indices

Tags: unit-testing, junit, lucene, legacy-code

I'm working on legacy code that builds an index of popular terms in another index. There are no unit tests in place, and the indexing process is a pain to wait for because the first index takes so long to build.

I want to structure the second (popular term) index differently. Is there a best practice for testing to see if a Lucene index is being created properly?

**EDIT>>** Per @Pascal's advice I'm using a RAMDirectory, then to test the index I just wrote I set up an indexReader and iterate through the term results, printing out each term to make sure the data looks alright.

Code:

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(dir2);
TermEnum terms = reader.terms();
System.out.println("Here come the terms!");
while (terms.next()){
    if (terms.term().field().equals("FULLTEXT")){
        System.out.println(terms.term());
    }
}
int numDocs = reader.maxDoc();
System.out.println("Number of Docs: " + numDocs);
```

If the index is really large I let it run for a bit then just stop it midway through.

Also, [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) is a great tool for inspecting the index if you want to be more thorough... I'm just looking for something fast.

Any other ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When unit-testing Lucene index, I often use the RAMDirectory as it is quick to build.

Comment: Yes, it won't persist to disk, but it will stay in memory for the time of the test.